# R:argument is of length zero

Tags: r, rstudio, data-science

I'm getting the error `argument is of length zero` when I am passing my dataframe and its respective columns to a custom function.

I made a function that checks if the value in one column is equal to value in any other columns, it should return a value in a new column of the dataframe named `data$group`.

```
//Name of Data Frame is 'data'


bucket.function<-function(df2, a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i) {

 if(df2$a==df2$b)
        result<- "if"

 else if(df2$a==df2$c)
        result<-"df"

 else if(df2$a==df2$d)
        result<-"bus"

 else if(df2$a==df2$e)
        result<-"car"


    else if(df2$a==df2$f)
        result<-"train"

    else if(df2$a==df2$g)
        result<-"exp"

    else if(df2$a==df2$h)
        result<-"dh"

    else if(df2$a==df2$i)
        result<-"ih"

    else 
        result<- "NA"

    return(result)
}

data$group <- bucket.function(data, "latest_txn_date", "if_last_txn_date", "df_last_txn_date", "b_last_txn_date", "car_last_txn_date", "train_last_txn_date", "exp_last_txn_date", "dh_last_txn_date", "ih_last_txn_date")
```

I expect the output to be a column of values in `data$group` that contains values returned for each value of `d$a`, here `data$latest_txn_date`

Comment: Please provide a part of `data` using `dput`

Comment: You can't use the `$` notation with variable column names - you will need to refer to the columns as `df[,a]` rather than `df$a` etc.

Answer (score 0):

`df2$a` is not in your dataframe as you have no `a` column. You have to access it with `df2[[a]]` that evaluate the value of `a`/. It is the same principle for arguments `a` to `i`.
Moreover you compare two vectors in your `if` conditions. I assume you want a different result for each row. Please have a look at the function `switch`.

Comment: This is correct, although R is noticeably faster if you use `df[,a]` rather than `df[[a]]`.  The latter treats `df` as a list, so avoids some of the optimised code that is designed for dataframes.

Comment: Thank you, i didn't know that. I have always prefered `[[]]` as it remembered that a dataframe is a special list.

Comment: @AndrewGustar Are you sure about that? [Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Performance.html) seems to indicate otherwise, and so did my own bechmarking.

Comment: @niko Interesting - the first version benchmarks faster on my machine.  Sounds like it probably doesn't matter much!